# foreignkey relationships not appear in edmx with mysql database with asp mvc with database first

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, model-view-controller, edmx

I have connected my asp.net MVC application with MySQL database, and included all the tables in edmx, but there is no relationships appeared in the designer, as shown in the image:

[image]

I tried to change the Entity Framework and MySQL ddls in manage nuggets page versions but not worked with me

---

database create queries:

**AnnualMilestone table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `AnnualMilestone` (
 `AnnalReport_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Milstone_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `IsCompleted_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CompletionDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `Justification` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `NewDeadLine` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `CreatedBy_Id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CreatedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `LastModifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `LastModifiedBy_Id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`AnnalReport_Id`,`Milstone_Id`),
 KEY `FK_ISCOMPLETED` (`IsCompleted_Id`),
 KEY `FK_MILSTONE_ANNAUL` (`Milstone_Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**AnnualReport table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `AnnualReport` (
 `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Project_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ReportingYear` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `SupportReceived` float NOT NULL,
 `SupportSpentOnMitigation` float NOT NULL,
 `IsCompleted_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Phase_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `WorkFlowStatus_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `LastModifiedBy_Id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
 `LastModifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `CreatedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `CreatedBy_Id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
 `IsWFCompleted_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `MinistryAnnualReport_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `StatusBeforeCancel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
 KEY `FK_ANNUALPHASE` (`Phase_Id`),
 KEY `FK_ANNUALWFSTATUS` (`WorkFlowStatus_Id`),
 KEY `FK_STATUSBEFORECANCEL` (`StatusBeforeCancel`),
 KEY `FK_WFCOMPLETED` (`IsWFCompleted_Id`),
 KEY `FK_YESNO` (`IsCompleted_Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Did you create any foreign keys in the database? Show us your create table statements

Comment: yes i created the relationships, check the updated question please

Comment: MyISAM doesn't have proper support for foreign keys (or transactions and other useful things). It's a legacy technology and hasn't been the default in mySQL for a long time. It may even get removed entirely in the future. Use the innoDB table engine instead

Comment: thanks dear, i have altered all tables to innoDB , but still the same problem, any more suggestions please

Comment: did you go back and re-create all the foreign keys properly after you changed the table engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL to create FK key:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

Comment: thank you, the issue was in createing the fk  not in the codes or edmx, best regards

Answer (score -1):

in the sql object explorer in your table did you refer to your foreign key
ex :  foreign key ([Milstone_Id]) references [db].[your table whith the PK_ID here Milistone] (["name of your FK here" Milstone_Id])
[image]